# How to compare XML arrtibute values of different element in perl

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I am writing script to compare the attribute values of `<book>` element in two different files and need to find any difference in attribute value. The **XML** code will look like as follows. The attribute needs comparison is 'revision' in book element:

```
<book fpi="9780133125900" status="PearsonML 9.8" revision="3">
<book fpi="9780133125900" status="PearsonML 9.8" revision="2">
```

Can anyone check and advise me to get it done in Perl script. I extracted the value but unable to compare.

```
##for extracting 'revision' vaue in file1
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => $find);
my $hname = $xp->find('/book/@revision');
##for extracting 'revision' vaue in file2
my $xx = XML::XPath->new(filename => $find1);
my  $hnaee = $xx->find('/book/@revision');
```

Best regards,
Bhuvana

Comment: you should probably use XML::LibXML instead of XML::XPath, it's faster, more memory efficient, more powerful and better maintained. The code will be very similar, so switching wouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `to_literal()` function to extract the number from the nodeset. It returns a reference to scalar, so dereference it in comparison:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::XPath;

#for extracting 'revision' vaue in file1
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => $find);
my $hname = $xp->find('/book/@revision')->to_literal;
##for extracting 'revision' vaue in file2
my $xx = XML::XPath->new(filename => $find1);
my  $hnaee = $xx->find('/book/@revision')->to_literal;

if ( $$hname == $$hnaee ) { 
    print "Equal\n";
}
else {
    print "Not equal";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. But I am getting 'Not a SCALAR' variable for the usage of "if ( $$hname == $$hnaee ) ". Could you please check and advise me.

Comment: @Bhuvana: With your XML files (fixed with a closing `/>` tag) and this script executed like `perl script.pl` I don't get any errors. I don't know. Check that you didn't make a typo or your xml data is too different. Also, use `Data::Dumper` and print the variables just before the comparison. And finally, I added that part of the code to show that it worked, you will need a different implementation, so remove it and use your own code.